# Why does the while loop not terminate?

Tags: c

The code is written to solve the Towers of Hanoi using stack operations, but output gets printed into the indefinitely.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

struct stack{
int a[MAX_SIZE];
int top;
}x, y, z;

typedef struct stack stk;

void push(stk *s, char n)
{
  if(s->top == MAX_SIZE-1)
    printf("Stack Overflow\n");
  else
    s->a[++s->top] = n;
}

int pop(stk *s)
{
  if(s->top < 0)
  {
    printf("Stack Underflow\n");
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    return s->a[s->top--];
  }
}

int top(stk *s)
{
  if(s->top < 0)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    return s->a[s->top];
  }
}

int isEmptyStack(stk *s)
{
  if(s->top < 0)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

int isFullStack(stk *s)
{
  if(s->top == MAX_SIZE - 1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

int size(stk *s)
{
  return s->top;
}

int main()
{
    x.top = -1;
    y.top = -1;
    z.top = -1;

    int n;
    printf("Enter number of disks: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        push(&x, i+1);
    }

    if(n > 0)
    {
        while(size(&z) < n-1)
        {
            if(n % 2 != 0)
            {
                if(top(&x) > top(&z))
                {
                    push(&z, pop(&x));
                    printf("X to Z\n");
                }
                if(top(&z) > top(&x))
                {
                    push(&x, pop(&z));
                    printf("Z to X\n");
                }

                if(top(&x) > top(&y))
                {
                    push(&y, pop(&x));
                    printf("X to Y\n");
                }
                if(top(&y) > top(&x))
                {
                    push(&x, pop(&y));
                    printf("Z to X\n");
                }

                if(top(&y) > top(&z))
                {
                    push(&z, pop(&y));
                    printf("Y to Z\n");
                }
                if(top(&z) > top(&y))
                {
                    push(&y, pop(&z));
                    printf("Z to Y\n");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if(top(&x) > top(&y))
                {
                    push(&y, pop(&x));
                    printf("X to Y\n");
                }
                if(top(&y) > top(&x))
                {
                    push(&x, pop(&y));
                    printf("Y to X\n");
                }

                if(top(&x) > top(&z))
                {
                    push(&z, pop(&x));
                    printf("X to Z\n");
                }
                if(top(&z) > top(&x))
                {
                    push(&x, pop(&z));
                    printf("Z to X\n");
                }

                if(top(&y) > top(&z))
                {
                    push(&z, pop(&y));
                    printf("Y to Z\n");
                }
                if(top(&z) > top(&y))
                {
                    push(&y, pop(&z));
                    printf("Z to Y\n");
                }   
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the condition `size(&z) < n-1` to become `0` which would terminate the loop, but the loop isn't terminating.

Terminal:

```
Enter number of disks: 3
*Out of control output*
```

It was suggested that I use a debugger, but I don't know how to, as I am only in the process of learning to use it.

Comment: Add some prints showing the values involved, use a debugger to step over. You need to develop some debugging skills as you can't expect every program to work right away as intended.

Comment: To debug without using an actual debugger, sprinkle output statements all over that each tell you where the logic is executing and what the values of key variables are at that point.

Comment: > It was suggested that I use a debugger, but I don't know how to, as I
> am only in the process of learning to use it.

Install Eclipse IDT IDE and start debugging :)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThYE5IllvB0

Comment: Thank you very much @0___________, but is there any tutorial on using a debugger on VS code instead? If not I shall use Eclipse IDE for debugging.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An infinite loop means that the loop condition, in this case `size(&z) < n-1`, remains true forever.  As the right hand side (rhs) `n-1` is fixed with `n = 3` this means you expect `size(&z)` to increment to at least 2 but it never does.  From the output we see a repeating cycle:

```
Z to X
X to Y
Z to X
X to Z
Z to X
...
```

which tells us that we pushed a value to `z` and popped it right off again so we never make progress.

I suggest you rework your interface so your error domain (-1) and value domain doesn't overlap.  If you `push(..., -1)` now you cannot tell when `top(...)` returns -1 if it's an error or of it just happens to be the last value you pushed.  `pop()` has the same issue, and again, caller cannot tell but at least there is an error message.

In your case either disallow push of -1, or have functions return the status of the operation and return the value via a pointer you passed in (using a constant OK here to improve readability):

```
#define OK 0

int push(stk *s, char n) {
    if(s->top == MAX_SIZE-1) {
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
        return !OK;
    }
    s->a[++s->top] = n;
    return OK;
}

int pop(stk *s, int *v) {
    if(s->top < 0) {
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
        return !OK;
    }
    *v = s->a[s->top--];
    return OK;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Allan Wind. 
But the 'pop(...)' function has to return 0 if We have a Stack Underflow right? So 'OK' must be defined as 1 right? Please correct me if I was wrong as I am only a beginner. :)

Comment: @DivyanshuMahi Usually, 0 means success and non-zero (possible more than 1 value) an error.  This is what my code does above, but you can define your interface any way you like.   It would even better to use an enum error { OK, UNDERFLOW, OVERFLOW } then you prototype will document that it's an enum and not just any old int that happens to have meaning assigned to it.